# How to make audio work in raspbian on qemu

Tags: audio, raspbian, qemu

Does anybody know how to enable audio support in raspbian running in qemu ?

lsmod shows nothing.
aplay -l shows no sound cards.
Tried with qemu ac97 and hda intel, running qemu inside ubuntu box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't say what QEMU board model you're trying to use (what argument you're passing the -machine or -M option), and there are at least two different plausible things you could be using. The answer to your question depends on which one you're using. If you're using 'versatilepb' then you probably need to get your guest to handle the pl041 audio that board has; if you're using 'raspi2' then the issue is that QEMU doesn't yet implement the audio parts of that board/SoC, I think.

Comment: Have you found any solution in the meantime?